# Reactor Kafka Graceful Shutdown and Pause Consumer

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, project-reactor, spring-webclient, graceful-shutdown

Spring Application uses Reactor Kafka to consume messages.

**Question 1: Is there standard convention to pause message consumption and finish processing inflight messages during application shutdown?**

Current implementation is to use `reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate` to receive messages. Then using `@Predestroy`, we pause consumer using `reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.pause`.

Current Implementation (simplified)

```
reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate
  .receiveAutoAck()
  .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
  .flatMap(x -> Mono.just(x)
      .delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(300)),5)
  .flatMap(message -> Mono.just(message)
     .flatMap(processMessageImp::processMessage)
     .onErrorResume(t -> Mono.empty())
  );

public void pauseKafkaMessageConsumer() {
  reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate
    .assignment()
    .flatMap(topicParts -> reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.pause(topicParts))
    .subscribe();
}

@PreDestroy
public void onExit() {
  pauseKafkaMessageConsumer();
  try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    log.error("onExit Error while PreDestroy ");
  }
}
```

**Question 2: How to prevent WebClientRequestException when using @Predestroy**

However during shutdown after the `Thread.sleep` in `@Predestroy`, any inflight messages fail due to `WebClientRequestException` . Messages processed during the `Thread.sleep` process successfully.

```
WebClientRequestException: executor not accepting a task; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: executor not accepting a task
```

Webclient implementation uses Springs injected builder

```
private final WebClient.Builder builder;

public WebClient createWebclient() {
  ...
  return builder.build()
}
```

`WebClientRequestException` seems to only happen when using Spring's injected Webclient.Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I took a similar approach that seems to work locally during testing. It pulls from and sends messages to the same topic as part of processing to test that it successfully consumes all of them before shutting down.

Now to be fair, I am not sure if this is a great approach. I'm still kinda new to Kafka, and could use some feedback!

```
  @NonNull
  private ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String,String> kafkaConsumerTemplate;

  @NonNull
  private ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String,String> kafkaProducerTemplate;

  @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.partitionCount}")
  private Integer topicPartitionsCount;

  private boolean shuttingDown;
  private final Composite disposables = Disposables.composite();

  @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
  public void postConstruct() {
    for (int i = 0; i < topicPartitionsCount; i++) {
      disposables.add(readWrite().subscribe());
    }
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void preDestroy() {
    shuttingDown = true;

    kafkaConsumerTemplate.assignment()
        .delayElements(Duration.of(20, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
        .flatMap(o -> kafkaConsumerTemplate.pause(o)).subscribe();
  }

  public Flux<MyMessage> readWrite() {
    return kafkaConsumerTemplate
        .receiveAutoAck()
        .takeUntil(item -> shuttingDown)
        .flatMap(item -> ingest(item.value()))
        .flatMap(item -> kafkaProducerTemplate.send("example_topic", GsonFactory.getGson().toJson(item)).thenReturn(item))
        .onErrorContinue((exception, errorConsumer) -> log.error("Exception while processing", exception));
  }
```